# Gulp-error-notifier change error message

Tags: gulp

I am building a jade error notification.

this is the code I have

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
   return gulp.src('local/*.jade')
       .pipe(errorNotifier())
       .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('local/'));
});
```

It does show an error message when the jade file is having some sort of error.
Is there a way to customize the message shown on my Mac.

To something like:

Jade error
Check terminal

In the terminal the error message is fine.

Comment: Without indication of what errornotifier() is, it could be pretty difficult. Please specify the package used in your gulp.

Comment: @DavideMelfi https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-error-notifier

Comment: var notify = require('gulp-error-notifier').notify;   notify(new Error('Something happened!'));